# installing swing hook before concrete is poured

Tags: concrete

I want to place a swing hooks in place before the concrete is poured so that , i dont have to drill a hole later. My contractor is not ready to make these bolts with TMT bars itself.. what kind of hooks or bolts should i buy for this purpose and how should it be installed. I expect the swing to handle around 1000lbs of weight.

Comment: The structural engineer who has designed the ceiling for half a ton dynamic loading should also have an idea for the hook.

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to plug in commercial products here, but you can search for 5/8" hold-down anchor bolts. They can take 3500-4000lbs.

They require the ear of the bolt to cross the top slab reinforcement, but they need a 13inch min embedment in concrete, not more than 45 degrees slant.

You have to check with your engineer if the slab is strong enough to take the dynamic load of 1000lbs, which usually has a load factor of 2.8.